# Корректно ли в конструкторе так инициализировать self.set_params(user="")?

Tags: python, ооп, инициализация, атрибуты

Как вы считаете, корректно ли так инициализировать атрибуты?

```
class Infobase:

    def __init__(self, server):
        self._server = server
        self.set_authentication_params(user='', password='')
        
    def set_authentication_params(self, user, password):
        self._user = user
        self._password = password
```

У меня достаточно много атрибутов в классе, и я разделил тематически их установку в разные функции типа set, например set_authentication_params. Мне нужно, чтобы во время создания объекта все атрибуты были созданы с пустыми значениями для начала, чтобы в дальнейшем исключить ошибки, что нет атрибута.

Comment: Вполне корректный вариант.

Answer (score 1):

Не плохо. Вот вам еще в копилку вариант с использованием значений по умолчанию

```py
class Infobase:

    def __init__(self, server, user=None, password=None):
        self._server = server
        self._user = user
        self._password = password
```

Или с необязательными именнованными параметрами

```py
class Infobase:

    def __init__(self, server, **kwargs):
        self._server = server
        if kwargs.get("user") and kwargs.get("password"):
            self._user = kwargs.get("user")
            self._password = kwargs.get("password")
        else:
            print("При инициализации объкта, есть возможность использовать пару (user, password). Объект инициализирован с пустыми полями user/password")
            self._user = None
            self._password = None
```